# What is the best way to contact a retired professor for a job reference?

Tags: job-search

I graduated from college in July, and I need to get someone to be a job reference. I have one from a previous job, but I need a second one. The recruiter indicated that I could use a professor with whom I'd taken a class as a reference.

I've contacted my former faculty advisor, who informed me that as a general rule, department faculty prefers not to be references for people who have only taken one class with them. In other words, the professor who is most likely to agree to be a reference is a professor with whom I have taken at least two classes.

Unfortunately, there is only one professor I can think of that meets the criteria I described, and said professor is retired.

How should I contact him?

Answer (score 23):

Try sending a nice e-mail! Us retired faculty still exist and writing strong letters of recommendation does not come to a full stop instantly. In any event, it does not hurt to ask. The professor’s e-mail address may be on their department’s web site, if you do not have it already. Best of success!

By the way, that “general rule” you mention may be more like “parlay” in the first “Pirates of the Caribbean” movie: not a real thing all that much. In any event, individual faculty members decide for themselves if they want to write letters of recommendation: they are not in trouble if they do so. And retired faculty have even more freedom: we are free range!

Comment: The university gave him an @x.edu address for official communication with students, which, as far as I can tell, is still registered to him. Would it be safe to use this e-mail address, or should I look for a different e-mail address to use?

Comment: I think so: mine is of that form. If he decides to write you a strong letter of recommendation, please make it as easy as possible by sending him your updated resume/vita and giving him some highlights you would especially like emphasized. One nice thing is that students cannot really boast about accomplishments, but professors can do that, and do it effectively, having read and written many such letters.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: This is not necessarily for a letter of recommendation. I'm seeking permission to list him as a reference on job applications (and I told the professor as such)

Comment: No problem: a heads up is always welcome, even if the reference never gets called.

Comment: "We are free range!" <--- I've never looked forward to retiring before!

Comment: @Araucaria Indeed, but there is a problem with retirement I never expected: time flies *faster* than when not retired! So all those soul-sapping committee meetings and such were actually  keeping Time from going by too fast. Kind of a rip-off.

Answer (score 0):

To more directly answer your question, if you don't have a contact for them or you're not certain if it works, ask the department to contact them on your behalf!

Something like

> Good temporal greeting,
>
> I am a former student of XYZ, but I'm not sure if their email _@example.edu is still valid, is there an appropriate account I can contact them at, or would you please help them contact me?
>
> Specifically, I'd like to request a letter of recommendation for a job and also to reconnect.
>
> Choice-of-thanks,
>
> Name

It would imo be unusual for any retired professional not to occasionally assist or be interested in their area of expertise, and professors are no exception - it's likely that if they remember and you both got on well that they'd be delighted to oblige any such small request, and also have more (arguably) spare time each day since retiring